# Difference between setting IIS Bindings and editing Windows hosts file?

Tags: iis-7.5

I used Visual Studio and IIS to successfully deploy a web project to the localhost. Go to localhost on port 51? Great, it pulls up. Wonderful.

Then I tried to add a binding so I could type in "example:51" and it would pull up the website. I then got the following error in chrome:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> example’s server DNS address could not be found.
>
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Looking around, some answers said to alter the hosts file in Windows. I did that, and it solved everything. I type in "example:51", I'm directed to localhost, which pulls up the website.

Then I completely removed the "example" binding from IIS, and it still worked fine. I wasn't so much adding a binding as changing the way "example" is interpreted. It also sends me to localhost on every other port as well, including 80, which I don't think a binding would have done.

So now I'm thinking I didn't solve the bindings problem correctly. Should I have done something differently?

Answer (score 0):

IIS bindings tell IIS how to respond when it receives a request for a specific hostname.
You probably have IIS configured to respond with your site regardless of hostname, so that doesn't matter.

IIS bindings have nothing to do with DNS or name resolution, which is how the browser knows that `example` should resolve to your host.